# How to change a column of expressions to values by assinging a value to the terms?

Tags: r, date

m trying to make a dynamic time series where I can match one data frame of expressions to one with dates.

For example:

df1 looks like:

| time | value | option |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t-3 | 100 | A |
| t-2 | 110 | A |
| t-1 | 120 | A |
| t-3 | 270 | B |
| t-2 | 459 | B |
| t-1 | 373 | B |

df2 looks like:

| start | option |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | A |
| 2025 | B |

I want my result to look like:

| time | value | option |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 100 | A |
| 2018 | 110 | A |
| 2019 | 120 | A |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2024 | 373 | B |

I can join the data frames but not sure how to take the time column and convert to date

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of providing your data as tables, can you provide your data using `dput()` as well as include any code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~time, ~value, ~option,
  "t-3",   100L,     "A",
  "t-2",   110L,     "A",
  "t-1",   120L,     "A",
  "t-3",   270L,     "B",
  "t-2",   459L,     "B",
  "t-1",   373L,     "B"
)
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~start, ~option,
  2020L, "A",
  2025L, "B"
)

library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
full_join(df1, df2) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    time = eval(parse(text = glue("function(t){time}")))(start)
  ) |>
  select(-start) |>
  ungroup()
```